# Выбрать первый символ perl

Tags: perl

Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос.
Есть $id - оно может быть значения P123 - D21312321 - т.е. первый символ всегда буква, затем разное количество цифр.

Удалить первую букву могу

```
my $nid = substr($id,1);
```

А как сделать наоборот? Мне нужно получить первую букву в $mid, например. Чтобы потом, в зависимости от буквы делать там свои действия.
Пробовал

```
my $mid = substr($id,1,1);
```

Естественно, не работает. Может я гуглю не верно? Не могу найти ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что второй аргумент принимает "номер" начального символа. А нумерация начинается с 0. Правильно так:

```
substr($id,0,1)
```